# "Wait for everything but particular usbmodem" zsh regular expression

Tags: macos, usb, zsh

I am writing firmware for different devices that communicate with each other and both of them are connected to my mac by USB. I am using `zsh`. First one is always on `/dev/tty.usbmodem1` and for some stupid mac-resons every next device will be on random modem number. Let's say second one is on `/dev/tty.usbmodem11`.
I am using following command to upload my firmware:

```
tools/uploader.py --port='/dev/tty.usbmodem*' Images/image.file
```

If it doesen't find any devices under usbmodem it will wait for the first one to appear.

### What I want is to make regular expression for this `--port=` to return anything **but** `/dev/tty.usbmodem1`

to be able to upload firmware on the second device while still connected to first one (which is always on `usbmodem1`).
I was trying:

```
tools/uploader.py --port='/dev/tty.usbmodem* | egrep \"usbmodem1$\" -v' Images/image.file
```

But it is not working if I plug in a device while this script is waiting for it. (script can wait for device using first command, as I wrote above).

Comment: As the parameter for `--port` is enclosed in single quotes, it is passed unaltered to `uploader.py`, so the shell cannot help here. What you can try is, if `tools/uploader.py --port=/dev/tty.usbmodem2 --port=/dev/tty.usbmodem3 Images/image.file` is working. If so, there are multiple ways zsh can help.

Comment: Yes, this is working. Can you give an example of implementing this list with zsh? I would prefer one-liner to few lines script. :)

Comment: Ended up modifying python script so it is accepting --except parameter now.

Comment: _Can you give an example of implementing this list with zsh?_ Of course, I just wanted to know that uploader.py can handle multiple `--port` parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comment you confirm that a command line like

```
tools/uploader.py --port=/dev/tty.usbmodem2 --port=/dev/tty.usbmodem3 Images/image.file
```

is working. To write a more general answer I melt it down to

```
echo foo --bar=file2 --bar=file3 ...
```

which everybody can test with copy & paste. So, I have two zsh'ish approaches in mind.

1. Use the construction scheme `fileN` where `N` is a number starting from 2 until lets say 5. Then you can use brace expansion:

   ```
   $ echo foo --bar=file{2..6}
   foo --bar=file2 --bar=file3 --bar=file4 --bar=file5 --bar=file6
   ```

   This does not care if `fileN` is actually a file or if it exists. It's just a text.
2. Use the glob qualifier `P`, which *prepends* a string (delimited e.g. by `:`) to the result of a globbing pattern (`file*`):

   ```
   $ echo foo file*(P:--bar:)
   foo --bar file1 --bar file2 --bar file3 --bar file4 --bar file5 --bar file7
   ```

   I. e. the result depends what files exist, in my example `file1` to `file5` and `file7`.

   But wait, you want to exclude `file1`, so modify the glob pattern to `file(^1)` which is short for `file(*^1)` and should be read as `file*` *but not* (^) `file1`:

   ```
   $ echo foo file(^1)(P:--bar:)
   foo --bar file2 --bar file3 --bar file4 --bar file5 --bar file7
   ```

   Or use `file<2->`, which matches `file2` onward:

   ```
   $ echo foo file<2->(P:--bar:)
   foo --bar file2 --bar file3 --bar file4 --bar file5 --bar file7
   ```

   Be aware that this glob qualifier inserts a space after the prefix. This might be an issue, but I wanted to include this approach, too, because it is usually very handy.

Comment: Perfect answer. I will leave my python edited uploader as a working solution, but this answer is great for general knowledge of zsh! Thank you sir.